# Unresponsive program with displaying a pressed key and using 'q' to exit program

Tags: visual-c++

I am following a tutorial video on how to make a very simple game using C++.  I am very early in the tutorial and I had no issues until now.  Accourding to the video when I run the program it should display any key I press with "Here's what you pressed: (pressed key goes here)".  Also, it should exit the program when I press the Q key.  On the video it works fine, but sadly on my screen it is just a blank DOS prompt that does not respond to anything.  Can anyone please look at what I got so far and see if there is a way to troubleshoot this issue.  Again, I am new at this so any help would be greatly appreciated.  Perhaps there is a header missing or something...

**game.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>    //Include this and namespace in all files.
using namespace std;

#include "game.h"
#include <conio.h>

bool Game::run(void)
{
char key = ' ';

while (key != 'q')
{
    while (!getInput(&key))
    {
    }

    cout << "Here's what you pressed: " << key << endl;
}

cout << "End of the game" << endl;
return true;
}

bool Game::getInput(char *c)
{
if (kbhit())
{
    *c = getch();
}

return false;
}
```

**game.h**

```
#ifndef GAME_H //Make sure this accompanies #endif.
#define GAME_H

class Game
{
public:
bool run (void);

protected:
bool getInput (char *c);
void timerUpdate (void);
};

#endif //Make sure this accompanies #ifndef.
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "game.h"


int main ()
{
Game gameHeart;

gameHeart.run();

return 0;
//system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Game.getInput` always returns `false`, so `Game.run` would endlessly ask for a keyboard input. Here's the fix.

```
bool Game::getInput(char *c)
{
    if (kbhit())
    {
        *c = getch();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  That was not used in the video, yet it still worked for in it.  Oh well...  It is funny how such a simple fix can solve a huge problem.  You have my gratitude.  Now I can continue.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the kbhit method is returning false and you are never prompted for key input. You can easily test this by commenting out that line so that getch() is guaranteed to be called.

Comment: Thank you for the help.  You were on the right track.  Check out the following answer for the full solution.